# combine foreign key with triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables as follows,

1. Evaluator Table
2. Answer Table
3. Evaluator Answer Table

Evaluator Answer table is linked other two tables ( it has two foreign keys to other two tables ). What I need is to delete all the answers provided by evaluator when evaluator is deleted from the evaluator table. I created a trigger to delete answers when records of Evaluator Answer table is deleted. So expected result is,

1. delete evaluator from Evaluator table
2. delete corresponding records from Evaluator Answer table ( using Foreign Key)
3. delete answers using a trigger

But problem is 3 rd step is not working. I directly delete a record from Evaluator Answer table . Then trigger works. Any one knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. It is not yet supported by mysql - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61555

Comment: Cascades don't fire triggers in MySQL because cascades and foreign key constraints in general are handled inside the storage engine layer, inside InnoDB, not at the server layer.  The code handling trigger firing isn't aware that the cascades occur.  Your workaround is to use `ON DELETE RESTRICT` and then use a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on the "evaluator" table to remove the child rows from the other tables first, instead of letting `ON DELETE CASCADE` handle it.